# Spice circuit Error : Must be an inductor or transmission line

Tags: circuit-analysis, spice

Hello I have an error on my spice circuit, I can not understand what is wrong?
able to help me?

**ERROR IMAGE:**
[image]

**ERROR:**

```
Must be an inductor or transmission line 
Name "kp" is defined more than once 
-NONE- 
Must be an inductor or transmission line
```

**CIRCUIT:**

```
Mn1 5 1 0 0 mosn L=0.5u W=7u
Mn2 5 2 0 0 mosn L=0.5u W=7u
Mn3 5 3 0 0 mosn L=0.5u W=7u
Mn4 6 4 5 0 mosn L=0.5u W=7u
Mp1 6 4 9 9 mosp L=0.5u W=7u
Mp2 6 3 7 9 mosp L=0.5u W=7u
Mp3 7 2 8 9 mosp L=0.5u W=7u
Mp4 8 1 9 9 mosp L=0.5u W=7u
.model mosp pmos Level=1 CGBO=4.5e-10, CGSO=3.5e-10, CGDO=3.5e-10, tox=8e-9, VTO=-1,
kp=50u, gamma=0.4
.model mosn nmos Level=1 CGBO=4.5e-10, CGSO=3.5e-10, CGDO=3.5e-10, tox=8e-9, VTO=1,
kp=100u, gamma=0.4
VCC 9 0 5V
CL 6 0 1pF
VA 1 0 5 pwl(0 5 10n 5 10.1n 0)
VB 2 0 5 pwl(0 5 10n 5 10.1n 0)
VC 3 0 5 pwl(0 5 10n 5 10.1n 0)
VD 4 0 5
.tran 100p 30n
.probe
.end
```

Comment: This is LTSpice you're using, correct? It just looks like an error log from LTSpice... thought I might ask.

Comment: @KingDuken this is Pspice Ad student! now I upload image of error!

Comment: Hint: SPICE originated in the 1970's and treats each line of text in its input as if it were a punch card. Continuing input from one card to the next requires special syntax.

Comment: Almost every language requires special syntax for line continuation.

Comment: This question goes through review a third time now. Can we please stop? How the hell is this opinion-based???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It clearly doesn't understand your trailing comma and whatever newline characters you've used as line continuation in your mosx models, so sees kp= as naming a new component, twice, which for a name starting with k must be an inductor or transmission line.

Simply removing the newline character(s) to allow it to be a single long line will let it work (or at least get rid of that error).

Alternatively if you do want to keep those lines broken, then a '+' in column 1 of the next line will continue the line (according to a SPICE 3 manual, likely to work the same for other flavours of SPICE, if not, RTrelevantM)

Comment: Spice's legacy of design based on punch-card input rears its ugly head again.